# Revealing part of a hidden div

Tags: css

I have 2 images. One will be a background the other will show a zoomed in version. Only a section of the zoomed in bit should be displayed - the part that intersects with the reveal div. So basically what I'd like to achieve in the code below is for the content of the circular (reveal) div to be red. If it is not possible to do it this way, how would it be possible?

```
<style type="text/css">
.base, .hidden{ 
  width:500px; height: 500px; 
  position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; 
}
.base { background: #800; } 
.hidden { background: #080; }
.reveal { 
  width: 200px; height: 200px; border-radius: 100px; 
  border: 5px solid #000;
  position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; 
}  
</style>
<div class="base">
  <div class="hidden"></div>
  <div class="reveal"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: like this? http://jsfiddle.net/p4Zs2/1/

Comment: Not quite, it would need to show the content from the hidden div within the circle; not just colour the circle red.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to achieve what I wanted in the end by using a clip path:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .a, .b {width: 500px; height: 500px; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0}
    .a{ background: red }
    .b{ background: green; -webkit-clip-path: circle(100px, 100px, 50px); }
</style>
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
```